# Java Pattern Regex Won't Match

Tags: java, regex

Can't figure out why the below pattern isn't matching for anything. Including some of my more simple test examples :

```
// Pattern attempts to match against a String containing ?[0-9]?+
Pattern groups = Pattern.compile(".*?\\?([2-9]+)\\?.*");        
Matcher m = groups.matcher("incSkl(?2?,2)");
int val = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
```

Even went super simple and tried feeding in a simple input of "?2?" to matcher. Still will error out on line 3.

Strangely the regex tester below seems to agree with me. It says both inputs should be a valid full match, without any flags needed on the Pattern
http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

What's going on here? I even threw something up on CoderPad just to make sure there wasn't something 'off' with my environment, and it errors with 'no match' as well.

I realize at this point I could probably do something with find() (and that option for this use case would be the most sensible), but I've never had anything like this happen, and at this point want to know why it can't do a full match when most other regex implementations go through with no problem.

Comment: What is the point of `\\**` in your pattern?  This will match zero or more occurrences of `*`, but if you didn't have it, the `.*` would match all the asterisks in your input anyway.  So having `\\**` makes no difference at all except to make your pattern uglier.

Comment: Looks like poor change management from when the pattern was "\\?([2-9]+)\\?\\**" Removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call:

```
m.find()
```

or

```
m.matches()
```

before calling: `m.group(1)` otherwise your code will throw a nice Exception at the time of calling `group()`

Comment: Yea. Just realized that a minute ago. Every other time I've ever used Matcher, I've had a if(m.matches()) beforehand. This time I didn't because at that place in the code the input is already validated. My until now perfect consistency with excessive error checking prevented me from ever realizing explicitly calling it was necessary!